# Regarding to save previous record in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi 
I have one label for question, radiobuttonlist for their answers, next button to move next question & previous button. I am displaying one question per page after clicking next button next question appears, but when i click previous button previous question appears.
But i want previous question with earlier selected answer when i click to previous button.
Asp.net c# Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either store and load Question and answer values in the session.

or have one page with a multiview and swich views when navigating between 'pages' this way the viewstate information will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net wizard too...

[Wizard Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx)

[Wizard Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Advanced Use of the ASP.NET Wizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)